# how to add a button to python

Tags: python

How can i add a button that open chrome in python I already wrote the window_page know I need the button here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Python GUI App")
window.configure(width=500, height=300)
window.configure(bg='lightgray')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: i couldn't understand your question, but it is a bad practice to use multiple if conditions, you could have used switch case statements

Comment: The question is *definitely* not clearly written, and a switch statement may well be a better option - but if I do understand the question correctly, you just need to use `else if` for all the `if` statements other than the first - so the structure is `if / else if / else if / else if [...] / else`

Comment: You need to use `else if`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies with your structure. If you use `else` it always refers to the last `if` and all `else if` between it. So if your last `if` is false, which happens if the `signL` is not `"%"` you will always enter the `else`.

To fix that you would need to fix your `if` statements, with use of `else if` statements.

**Example with IF Conditions:**

```cs
if (signL == "*") {
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn * secIn);
}
else if (signL == "+") {
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn + secIn);
}
else if (signL == "/") {
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);
}
else if (signL == "-") {
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn - secIn);
}
else if (signL == "%") {
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);
}
else {
    Console.Write("Wrong");
}
```

Or you could use a `switch` case which I would advise when you want to check for constant variables.

**Example with switch Case:**

```cs
switch(signL) {
case "*":
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn * secIn);        
    break;
case "+":
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn + secIn);        
    break;
case "/":
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);        
    break;
case "-":
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn - secIn);        
    break;
case "%":
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);        
    break;
default:
    Console.Write("Wrong");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `else if`?
because if your last condition `if (signL == "%")` is incorrect it would always redirect to `else` statement

```js
if (signL == "*")
{
   Console.Write("result is: ");
   Console.WriteLine(frsIn * secIn);
}
else if (signL == "+")
{
  Console.Write("result is: ");
  Console.WriteLine(frsIn + secIn);
}
else if (signL == "/")
{
  Console.Write("result is: ");
  Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);
}
else if (signL == "-")
{
  Console.Write("result is: ");
  Console.WriteLine(frsIn - secIn);
}
else if (signL == "%")
{
  Console.Write("result is: ");
  Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);
}
else
{
  Console.Write("Wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all but the first line, you want `else if` rather than just `if`. Even better would be a `switch` statement.

In the current code, consider if `signL` is "/". It fails tests 1, 2 and 4 but passed 3.

But then it fails 5 ("%") and therefore goes into the `else` clause, and so gives both the division result and "wrong".

Using `if else` would give:

```
if (signL == "*")
{
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn * secIn);
}
else if (signL == "+")
{
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn + secIn);
}
else if (signL == "/")
{
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);
}
else if (signL == "-")
{
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn - secIn);
}
else if (signL == "%")
{
    Console.Write("result is: ");
    Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);
}
else
{
     Console.Write("Wrong");
}
```

However, this is inefficient since with, for example "%" there will have been five comparisons - four fails an one pass.

A `select` only requires on comparison (of the string's has, to be precise):

```
switch (signL)
{
    case "*":
        Console.Write("result is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(frsIn * secIn);
        break;

    case "+":
        Console.Write("result is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(frsIn + secIn);
        break;

    case "/":
        Console.Write("result is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(frsIn / secIn);
        break;

    case "-":
        Console.Write("result is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(frsIn - secIn);
        break;

    case "%":
        Console.Write("result is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(frsIn % secIn);
        break;

    default;
        Console.Write("Wrong");
        break;
}
```